# How to change uri in request line in wrk

Tags: http, wrk

I'm trying to use wrk to send HTTP requests to our server.  I'm trying to create a HTTP package, but looks at the wrk structure definition for lua, it doesn't seem like there's any way to set the uri in the request line.
Does anyone know how its done?
thanks.

Comment: Do you have an example to which URI you are trying to reach?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean, exactly, but you can definitely set your path in the request function, e.g.:

```
names = { "Maverick", "Goose", "Viper", "Iceman", "Merlin", "Sundown", "Cougar", "Hollywood", "Wolfman", "Jester" }

request = function()
    wrk.method = "POST"
    wrk.path = "/test"   -- Is this what you're asking about?
    wrk.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
    body = '{"name": ' .. names[math.random(#names)] .. '}'
    return wrk.format(nil, nil, nil, body)
end
```